# Pivot table between two dates using SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have the following table:

**Example**:

```
create table test
(
  col_dt1 date,
  col_dt2 date
)
```

Inserting some records:

```
insert into test values('2014-11-07','2014-12-01');

select * from test;

col_dt1     col_dt2
----------------------
2014-11-07  2014-12-01
```

Expected Result:

```
col_dt1     col_dt2    07 November 2014  08 November 2014 .................... 01 December 2014
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-11-07  2014-12-01       1                 0          ....................        1
```

I got stuck to get all dates between two dates to have the stuff column in pivot table.

Comment: Expected output is not clear

Comment: @Pradeep, There are two dates understand that is first and last dates given as `2014-11-07` and `2014-12-01`. I want to show the pivot table for these dates starting from `2014-11-07` to `2014-12-01`. It has to show all the dates between these two dates in columns.

Comment: so u need value of 1 under those two dates, and for other dates value should be 0

Comment: @Meem What if your table contains one more row, e.g. (2014-01-01, 2014-01-31). What is the desired output in this case?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, Nope! The give date is used as the condition for start and end time according to which records will display.

Comment: @Meem In this case you might look into using a table valued function. Pivot is used to rotate table-valued expressions. What you have as an input is not a table-valued expressions. It simply is two scalar dates: a start date and an end date.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, +1 exactly! I need table valued function. I have gone through this -> http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/639460/Find-All-the-Days-Between-Two-Dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Start_Date DATE, @End_Date DATE, @QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX), @SUBQUERY NVARCHAR(MAX), @ROWCOUNT int

CREATE TABLE #TempTable(
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
Start_Date date,
End_Date date, 
Dates NVARCHAR(50),
HasDate int
)
CREATE TABLE #TempTable2(
Start_Date date,
End_Date date, 
Dates NVARCHAR(50), 
HasDate int
)

SET @Start_Date = (SELECT TOP 1 col_dt1 from test)
SET @End_Date = (SELECT TOP 1 col_dt2 from test)

INSERT INTO #TempTable
SELECT 
@Start_Date as Start_Date,
@End_Date as End_Date,
RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', DAY(DATEADD(DAY,number,@Start_Date))) + CAST(DAY(DATEADD(DAY,number,@Start_Date)) AS NVARCHAR(2)), 2)
+' '+DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(DAY,number,@Start_Date))+' '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),YEAR(DATEADD(DAY,number,@Start_Date))) as Start_Date,
HasDate =
      CASE 
         WHEN DATEADD(DAY,number,@Start_Date)=@Start_Date THEN 1
         WHEN DATEADD(DAY,number,@Start_Date)=@End_Date THEN 1
         ELSE 0
      END
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEADD(DAY,number,@Start_Date) <= @End_Date
INSERT INTO #TempTable2 SELECT [Start_Date],[End_Date],[Dates],HasDate FROM #TempTable

SELECT * FROM #TempTable

SET @QUERY=''
SET @QUERY+='SELECT * FROM #TempTable2
                PIVOT
                (
                    Max(HasDate)
                    FOR Dates IN ('

SET @SUBQUERY=''
SET @ROWCOUNT=1                 
WHILE @ROWCOUNT <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TempTable)
BEGIN
    SET @SUBQUERY=@SUBQUERY+'['+(SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),Dates)as Dates FROM #TempTable WHERE ID=@ROWCOUNT)+']'
    IF (@ROWCOUNT<>(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TempTable))
    BEGIN
        SET @SUBQUERY=@SUBQUERY+','
    END
    SET @ROWCOUNT=@ROWCOUNT+1
END             
SET @QUERY=@QUERY+@SUBQUERY+')
                )AS tblPivot'


PRINT(@QUERY)
EXECUTE(@QUERY)

DROP TABLE #TempTable
DROP TABLE #TempTable2
```

You can try this.